# AbsoluteUri and Original string in the HTTPWebRequest is different using C#

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I am facing this interesting issue and I was wondering if the community will have an explanation for this.

I send this HTTP web request query to run my code.

*https://Hostname/Path?xsauth=3a9cc813f7b56774c2c997406b654bf2&matchUsername=*&matchCount=200&action=Delete+Session...&selectedUser=sidfb405c963f9c6d201f9de8b14b3bd31d1ff3d09fffffffff%3Arshag2%7E%7EACYL-ARE*

However when I request above query it fails. Upon troubleshooting I find that the absoluteuri has changed it to below:

*https://Hostname/Path?xsauth=3a9cc813f7b56774c2c997406b654bf2&matchUsername=*&matchCount=200&action=Delete+Session...&selectedUser=sidfb405c963f9c6d201f9de8b14b3bd31d1ff3d09fffffffff:rshag2~~ACYL-ARE*

However I see that the original string (in HTTPWebRequest)contains the same query.

I was wondering if someone can explain me why the AbsoluteURI contains different query instead of requested query. And how can I send the original query to be executed.

Thanks and appreciate your help!

Comment: Looks like HttpWebRequest is unescaping the url. Try creating the Uri using one of the System.Uri constructors, and then create the webrequest with the Uri object as parameter.

Comment: Hi Feroze, I created a constructor using System.Uri but it gives the same result.                                                                                                        e.g. Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com/?json=" + %7E%7E); The AbsoluteUri in the HTTPWebRequest is still ~~ instead of %7E%7E.

Comment: I am not an expert with url encodings, but I would imagine that whatever it is giving back is a valid url, i.e. the tilde character doesnt need to be escaped. SO, why is the server denying this request? might be a server issue?

Comment: Two things. First, if I send %7E%7E it works. So the URL and the server side is fine. Second, I din't send the request yet, I still have to go through other parameters like Method, ContentType and so on before sending the request. This is something I find in the debug mode for the value of query. I have no idea why HTTPWebRequest modifies the query.

Comment: It tries to simplify the url. You dont need to escape characters that dont need escaping.